Identify this Rom-Com about the leads on a Greek holiday at the end
This is my first identify this movie question so please be gentle.  
Today morning, while sipping tea, I watched a movie(few scenes) on HBO. Those were the ending scenes as HBO, rather than displaying current
movie's name was mentioning the next scheduled movie.  
In one scene, the female lead(supposedly) is sitting at a restaurant on a hill side. She is writing something & asks an older women(supposedly
the owner) what "lost pants" means in Greek. To which the old women sternly replies "Greek women dont lose their pants"  
In the next scene, 3 other women(supposedly, female leads friends) arrive at the restaurant gate on a camel ride. The female lead is 
pleasantly surprised to see them. Their discussion is contextually incomprehensible to me.
In next scene, they are all on a cruise ship, where the female lead walks up to the male lead(supposedly). They both share an emotional history I 
suppose. The two break whatever remaining relationship they had. 
In the next scene, the female lead, rocking the bed, unable to sleep, walks out near the shore of a river & finds the male lead sitting in a
small boat. The two express that they never stopped loving each other & kiss.  
And then I had to go to office. Can anybody help me identify this rom-com movie. The movie looked recent, definitely post 2000.

So, since you clearly have Internet capability in order to post here, you write a lengthy piece, but don't go to HBO's schedule?

@wbogacz Stack Exchange is almost always text with few pictures & rare videos. Very easy to access during office hours. Try opening HBO's webpage & be discreet about it in office.

"Ahem, we've been noticing you've been spending office time writing to this website "StackExchange"? What do you have to say for yourself?" You: "At least I wasn't watching HBO" Mgt: "Well, there is something to be said for that. Take this recommendation we've written for you, while you seek new employment. We seek discretion here."

DONT FEED THE TROLL DONT FEED THE TROLL DONT FEED THE TROLL

Sounds like The Sisterhood of the Traveling Pants 2 (2008). From Wiki:

In the summer following their first year of college, we revisit four friends who have been apart all year and plan to spend their summer apart until a magical old pair of pants reunites them. [...] Lena (Alexis Bledel) finds her former flame Kostas (Michael Rady) married in Greece. [...] When Lena's sister Effie (Lucy Hale) steals and loses the Pants in Greece, the Sisterhood follows. Despite not finding the Pants, they reaffirm their friendship and commitment to the Sisterhood.

Here's that last scene with the kiss on the boat. And here's the trailer where they arrive at the restaurant on donkeys and also contains this dialogue in the end:

Lena: How do you say "lost pants" in Greek?
Yia Yia: Greek girls do not lose their pants! 




Oh, and it also aired this morning on HBO India. :)
